# Swift UI YouTube video view appears much larger on load then resizes

Tags: xcode, swiftui, video, youtube

Hello I have a simple YouTube video player view. When the video is rendering and loading it it appears very large with a blank white or black screen then when the video loads in it resizes to the correct frame. How can I adjust my methods so that the video doesn't appear large when it loads in. It currently covers other sub views because of its large size. Id appreciate the help. Thanks.

```
struct YouTubeView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let link: String
    let short: Bool
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        return WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
            var embedHTML = ""
            <body style="background-color:\(colorScheme == .dark ? "black" : "white");">
                <iframe
                width=450"
                height="280"
                src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/\(link)?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </body>
            """
        
        
        uiView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        uiView.loadHTMLString(embedHTML, baseURL: nil)
    }
}


Here's how it looks in a normal view:

   YouTubeView(link: link, short: false)
                .scaleEffect(2, anchor: .topLeading)
                .frame(width: 340, height: 205)
```